# ReactJs project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

After I initialized the project with the command: "npx create-react-app my-app", then I "cd into my-app" and ran the "npm start" command, what is the screen about cmd? So guys, can you give me instructions on how to handle this error, I thank you very much!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN2Gn.png)

Comment: You may need to scroll up in your console to see the origin of the error.  Though shouldn't the command be `npm run start`?

Comment: You might have to update your `create-react-app` verison, or update `node` version

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+alt+supr 
Open administrator tools 
Find and NodeJS instance kill all 
Then get in the folder where your project is 
Once inside run `npm install` then `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

Execute "npm install" before "npm start". "npm install" creates node modules folder without which you cannot run the application